# How to add mXparser library to Sketchware Pro?

Tags: java, android, sketchware

I am trying to add mxparser library to my Sketchware Pro project. I downloaded the .jar file of the library and copy paste it to local libraries folder manually. But when I open Sketchware and go to Local library, I don't see the file. Moreover I have tried by adding the library through "Local library > DX". But it says "library not found". Any suggestions on how to add mXparser library to Sketchware Pro project?

Comment: this vedio may be helpful : https://youtu.be/RsBxnSBkbV8

Comment: Thats looks helpful. I'll try and update.